# OnlyOffice проблема при запуске onlyoffice-community-server в кластере

Tags: ubuntu, bash, devops, kubernetes, onlyoffice

Ребята, всем привет! Использую к8s кластер для разворачивания Onlyoffice, в логах pod'a onlyoffice-community-server идёт запуск скрипта и на этом всё зависает ->

```
    /app/run-community-server.sh: line 184: & 255 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "& 255 ")
+ '[' true == true ']'
+ '[' onlyoffice-document-server == onlyoffice-document-server ']'
+ bash /app/assets/tools/wait-for-it.sh onlyoffice-document-server:8000 --quiet -s -- echo 'Document Server is up'
+ sleep 1
+ bash /app/assets/tools/wait-for-it.sh onlyoffice-document-server:8000 --quiet -s -- echo 'Document Server is up'
+ sleep 1
```

подскажите если кто сталкивался с данной проблемой.

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxtOw.png бесконечное ожидание

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Cg7X.png log

[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI7w4.png service

[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4YHQ.png pods

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена, открыл порт 8000 на сервере документов, в docker-compose на который я ссылался этот порт не был открыт.